# Referencing a Subform's Subform Control in another Module MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to reference a subform's subform control in VBA. I have a main form which, via buttons, opens up a subform. Within that subform are several buttons that open up another subform. Basically a Russian doll scenario with buttons.

The end goal is to have one function being called with the sub-subform's being used as a variable in a function called GetFile. The workaround right now is that I have different versions of the GetFile function in each sub-subform's VBA.

Here's the sub-subform's button click code:

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()
     Dim strForm As String

     strForm = Me.Name
     Call GetFile(strForm)
End Sub
```

Which then calls this module:

```
Function GetFile(strForm As String)

     Forms!frmMainMenu!subFrm.Form!subFrm!chkImport.Visible = True

End Function
```

Currently, I get this error: Runtime Error '2465'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

This is your case:

```
Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!Subform2.Form!ControlName.Enabled
```

so you probably want

```
Forms!frmMainMenu!subFrm.Form!subFrm.Form!chkImport.Visible = True
```

although your question is a bit confusing ("open a subform"? A subform is embedded in the parent form).

---

It may be easier to pass the form object instead of its name as parameter:

```
Call GetFile(Me)
```

then it doesn't matter where in the hierarchy the form is, simply use it directly:

```
Function GetFile(myForm As Form)

     myForm!chkImport.Visible = True

End Function
```

Comment: Well. You know what they say, easier option is always best. NO MATTER THE CIRCUMSTANCES.

Comment: :). But really, thanks! I was so stuck in the box of thinking to pass the form name as a string, that I didn't think of passing it as an object.

Comment: Oh. And sorry for being confusing. No excuses. I'm just dumb. :D